# CSS Background image not works

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

```
.menubar li {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(js/left_main_bg_image.gif);
}
```

The background-image is not works for ie, firefox, chrome.
I also got try it at table. not working also.

Can anyone help me!
I will appreciate who helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the height of the image to your CSS declaration too. And You don't need those `<br>` tags there

Something like below should work:

```
.menubar li {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('js/left_main_bg_image.gif');
     height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I also run it after clear all the browser cache. But the result is still same

Comment: if you see it runs only when given the full path. then your directory structure is not perfect and thats what is causing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `height` CSS property. See the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/LAYjP/).

Here is the required HTML & CSS. Compare with your code and see what you missed.

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menubar">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

​**CSS**

```
.menubar li {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px; 
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url(js/left_main_bg_image.gif);
}​
```

Comment: i got all thing u type, but i just have no image.
it only works when i put full path

Comment: Then check your URL. You may have missed out a `..` to go to the parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menubar li {
    float: left;
    width: 115px;
    height:100px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url('js/left_main_bg_image.gif');
}
```

notice the quotation marks around the image url...

and I have no idea why you have `<br>` elements in your css...

Comment: Quotation is not required.

Answer (score 0):

It is expecting the **li** elements to be inside **ol** or **ul** tags which have class as **menubar**.
Make sure these tags with the specified class is there.